# How to "Knit to PDF" a Rnotebook that uses SVG as backend rendering?

Tags: html, r, svg, rstudio, knitr

I'm `Knit to PDF` below document to PDF in Rstudio

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'svg') # set output device to svg
``` 

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```
````

Then I get an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile TP1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See TP1.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Execution halted
```

On the other hand, everything works fine when I `Knit to HTML`. The problem is certainly due to the first code cell. Is there anyway to solve this error?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @JoséCarlos Not yet :(

Comment: I had to set pdf_document: dev: 'svg'. If you don't use dev: 'svg' the problem is solved for ggplot2 plot outputs.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoséCarlos. I have not used R for over a year :v